# Grout in shower stays wet in some spots?

Tags: shower, grout, wet

A few years ago I had my shower redone- complete with tiled floor.  I believe the contractor did not seal the sanded grout for a few reasons to lengthy to mention.  After less then two months the grout started showing signs of staining and a few spots of cracking despite cleaning and my drying the shower after each use.  He showed me how to ‘patch’ the grout which I was told was due to normal movement of the walls etc.  For the sealing: After going back and forth on his schedule (setting up a time and then not showing)the contractor just gave me advice on cleaning the grout and which sealer to go buy to do the job myself.  Which I did.  Overall he thought I was being paranoid about water getting behind the tile since ‘it has a waterproof liner’, when I’m actually worried about mold. Fast forward to 2 years later and after trying to patch different spots I decided to tackle the areas I thought were a concern all at once.

While removing the old grout in some spots that I wasn’t sure about (appeared to be starting to crack or was discolored) I noticed some of the grout is actually not discolored but isn’t completely dry! This is along the front wall where the shower head and drain is but also in a few spots on the floor as well.  I started this over 24 hrs ago and the grout in those spots is still not dry despite my removing most of it.

My questions:

1. My concern is:  does this mean moisture is trapped under the floor tile?  Or just that some of the grout is compromised due to poor sealing?
2. if the advice is it’s fine I’ll work on regrouting.  But should I redo the silicone seam where the floor meets the wall?  I though I saw somewhere that some people do not recommend it?  The seam is very narrow in spots to where I wouldn’t be able to get grouting in some of them.

Note:  the areas on the floor not in question (grout seemed fine/solid/no cracking or discoloration) feels solid, the isn’t any give etc.  The tiles are not stone, they are ceramic or porcelain so no concern that water is going through them.

Comment: Well a color difference is normal, from your description you may be over thinking things.

Comment: You realize, I hope, that tile/grout is not watertight which is the reason you must have waterproof backer board and a pan to catch water that infiltrates the grout.  Sealing helps but still doesn't make it waterproof.

Comment: Fortunately from the response I’ll take it that is normal for some spots and finish the project without worry.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I do realize grout is not waterproof. This project started with me trying to fix areas where the grout had cracked causing a few small holes in the grout of my shower floor.  During the process of removing the cracked/broken grout I’d also noticed some grout id always thought was stained was actually never drying.  The concern was (In addition to fixing broken grout) was that the some old grout had not dried despite the shower not being used for 3 days.  Those areas were coming out with the ‘mud’ like wet consistency. That in addition to the broken grout is what caused the concern